# ubuntu 14.04 HDMI wrong resolution

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, resolution, hdmi, display-resolution

I recently purchased a NVIDIA GTX960 and having issue with my secondary monitory connected by hdmi cable ( using HDMI to VGA converter ).
The monitor in question is Acer X233H and has resolution of 1920x1080 .

But in the available resolution list, it only shows this:

```
khan@khan-P55A-UD3P:~/Desktop$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2726 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1366x768       59.8*+
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1360x768+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       60.0*    59.8  
   1152x864       60.0  
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
   680x384        60.0     59.8  
   640x480        59.9  
   512x384        60.0  
   400x300        72.2  
   320x240        60.1  
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

If i try to manually add the resolution , it gives the following error:

```
khan@khan-P55A-UD3P:~/Desktop$ cvt 1920 1080 60
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
khan@khan-P55A-UD3P:~/Desktop$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
khan@khan-P55A-UD3P:~/Desktop$ xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 1920x1080_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  47
  Current serial number in output stream:  48
```

Can anyone suggest what could be going wrong ? should I get **DisplayPort to VGA converter ( nvidia 960 has 3 DisplayPort, 1 HDMi and 1 DVI )** and will that solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate this is an old question. You have no doubt long since resolved this issue.

For anyone else who find this, I resolved this issue by heading to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and modifying to monitor `HorizSync` and `VertRefresh` values. I can't remember what they were but this is how the monitor section now appears.

```
Section "Monitor"
    ....
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    ....
EndSection
```